# Bluetooth pairing without user confirmation

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc

Can I pair two devices over Bluetooth without a need to confirm this in user interface, accept to pair this devices. Can I exchange some extra data over, for example NFC, and then safely pair those two devices over Bluetooth without any extra user action?

Comment: Smells like security breach, although I'm sure that Bluetooth technology has a ton of holes in it. I'm not sure that's legal though, and you application will most likely be removed from Android Market.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This need is exactly why `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()` was added to `BluetoothDevice` starting in Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10) ([SDK Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29))...before that there was no SDK support for this.  It was designed to allow Android to connect to devices without user interfaces for entering a PIN code (like an embedded device), but it just as usable for setting up a connection between two devices without user PIN entry.

The corollary method `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord()` in `BluetoothAdapter` is used to accept these types of connections.  It's not a security breach because the methods must be used as a pair.  You cannot use this to simply attempt to pair with any old Bluetooth device.

You can also do short range communications over NFC, but that hardware is less prominent on Android devices.  Definitely pick one, and don't try to create a solution that uses both.

Hope that Helps!

P.S. There are also ways to do this on many devices prior to 2.3 using reflection, because the code did exist...but I wouldn't necessarily recommend this for mass-distributed production applications.  See this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308373/how-to-create-insecure-rfcomm-socket-in-android/5319114#5319114).

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell me, if there is some BroadcastReceiver kinda thing available to know if some paired device is available? If not then, I think, I have to do a periodical polling which involves trying to connect to the required device. But connect is a blocking call and it will also set the toll on battery.

Comment: You my friend are a genius.  Adding one word to my code ("Insecure" as in createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()) made my legacy bluetooth device (GPS) work immediately.  It does not need a PIN code, so the secure connection was not working.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this should really be broken into 2 parts:

1. Can you pair 2 Bluetooth devices without going through a Bluetooth pairing handshake? No, you can't. That's baked into the protocol so there is no way around this.
2. Can you perform the handshake without a user interface? Yes, you can: that's just code.

I'm not sure how you do it in Windows land, but in *nix land there are functions buried in the Bluez stack that let you receive notifications about when a new device appears, and send it the pairing code (clearly there have to be these functions: those are what the user interface use). Given sufficient time and experience I'm sure you could figure out how to write your own version of the Bluetooth Settings app that somehow:

- Detected a new device had arrived
- Looked at the name/bluetooth mac address and checked some internal database for the pairing code to use.
- Sent the pairing code and completed the operation

All without having to pop up a user interface.

If you go ahead and write the code I'd LOVE to get my hands on it.

Comment: Hi, I am up for this even if you have little bit excitement. I am working on this currently in cordova. If you are available we can do this.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: When I send files between devices with OBEX I am almost never prompted to pair, so it is certainly possible.

1) An application and the device itself can each be set to need/not-need authentication modes, so often there was no requirement for pairing.  For instance most OBEX (OPP) servers don't need any authentication at all so there is not need for pairing/bonding.

Presumably "Wireless Designs"'s answer was covering that case.

2) Then if pairing was required by the device/app:

2.1) Prior to v2.1 for pairing then the two devices needed to have matching passphrase/PINs.  So this either needed user involvement (to enter the PINs) or knowledge in the softwareto know the PIN: either defined in the app `if pin callback send pin="1234"`, or smarts in the OS like BlueZ and Win7 (see [Slide 20 at my Bluetooth in Windows 7 doc](http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/Bluetooth%20in%20Windows%207.html)) which has logic like: `if(remotedevice=headset) then expectedPin ="0000"`.  Don't know what Android does

2.2) In v2.1 Secure Simple Pairing (SSP) was added.  Which changes pairing to:

> ```
> if (either is pre-v2.1) then
>    Legacy
> else if (Out-Of-Band channel) then
>    OutOfBand
> else if (neither have "Man-in-the-Middle Protection Required") then
>    (i.e. both have "Man-in-the-Middle Protection _Not_ Required")
>    Just-Works
> else
>    Depending on the two devices' "IO Capabilities", either NumericComparison or Passkey.
>    Passkey is used when one device has KeyboardOnly -- and the peer device _isn't_ NoInputNoOutput.
> endif
> ```

From [32feet.NET's BluetoothWin32Authentication user guide](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BluetoothWin32Authentication&referringTitle=Documentation), see also the SSP sections in [[1](http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/Bluetooth%20in%20Windows%207.html)]

So to have pairing be unprompted needs either "JustWorks" or "Out-of-Band" eg your NFC suggestion.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible in theory as defined by the specification.
However there is no practical implementation as yet that would allow this.

Refer: NFC Forum Connection Handover Technical Specification
http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/

Quoting from the specification regarding the security - 
*"The Handover Protocol requires transmission of network access data and credentials (the carrier configuration data) to allow one device to connect to a wireless network provided by another device. Because of the close proximity needed for communication between NFC Devices and Tags, eavesdropping of carrier configuration data is difficult, but not impossible, without recognition by the legitimate owner of the devices. Transmission of carrier configuration data to devices that can be brought to close proximity is deemed legitimate within the scope of this specification."*

Answer (score 0):

BT version 2.0 or less - You should be able to pair/bond using a standard PIN code, entered programmatically e.g. 1234 or 0000. This is not very secure but many BT devices do this.

BT version 2.1 or greater - Mode 4 Secure Simple Pairing "just works" model can be used. It uses elliptical encryption (whatever that is) and is very secure but is open to Man In The Middle attacks. Compared to the old '0000' pin code approach it is light years ahead. This doesn't require any user input.

This is according to the Bluetooth specs but what you can use depends on what verson of the Bluetooth standard your stack supports and what API you have.

Answer (score -3):

If you are asking if you can pair two devices without the user EVER approving the pairing, no it cannot be done, it is a security feature.  If you are paired over Bluetooth there is no need to exchange data over NFC, just exchange data over the Bluetooth link.

I don't think you can circumvent Bluetooth security by passing an authentication packet over NFC, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It seems that you were wrong. According to what I read on this page, the insecure bluetooth connection enable a communication without security, and the NFC connection can let both cellphones create a shared secret which can be used to encrypt the communication over bluetooth using a symmetric cipher like AES.