# Android zebra print not working on newer versions

Tags: android, zebra-printers

We are using `DiscoveredPrinterBluetooth` to keep discovered printer, `ZebraPrinterConnection` and `ZebraPrinter` to send data to printer. Everything is working ok on older android versions, but on let say 4.0 is not working, finds printer but keeps showing insert pin screen. Get error in log:

```
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(5371): ...connect(96, RFCOMM) = 111 (errno 111)
```

As I see there is problem with newer versions, looking at 
[Bluetooth pairing without user confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885438/bluetooth-pairing-without-user-confirmation)
but I don't know how to solve it in my case? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[The 2.0 version of the Zebra SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html) has an implementation of insecure bluetooth connections.

Check out `BluetoothConnectionInsecure` in the new SDK. This could be used instead of `BluetoothConnection` if you want insecure BT connections...