# 3DS Streetpass on Android with Bluetooth

Tags: android, json, bluetooth

Hi Stackers I'm working on a project but I don't know if it's possible to emulate the streetpass of the 3ds but using bluetooth on android. The idea it's simple, when two people cross with the app installed they exchange a json with info. It's really possible to do that?

Comment: Nintendo did it... donno why it should not be possible. Raise some security questions though, because, maybe, all 3ds know each other but bluetooth devices, usually need user intervention to sync with each other...

Comment: That's the point... i'm afraid because maby if we can't find a way to sync unknown devices we cant still with the project...

Comment: I was curious and, it seems to be there! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885438/bluetooth-pairing-without-user-confirmation

Comment: Thank's a lot :D I will read all the post.