# How to accept bluetooth received file in Android application?

Tags: android, file, bluetooth

I would like to implement an application to *receive a file from a Bluetooth device*.

Before receiving, a notification will be raised to accept an incoming file request.

From there, i would like to activate "accept" and download the file automatically without raising an accept dialog when the user receive a second file from another Bluetooth paired device, without notification disturbance when the user launchs an application.

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483758/android-programmatically-bluetooth-pairing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed an app that include this kind of task, and you can use [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.html) example. 
You must set the secure flag to false: 
`
boolean secure = false;

```
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                    MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);

        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }`
```

And then read the buffer from the InputStream that you can find in ConnectedThread:

```
while (true) {
            try {

                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                 /*write bytes in a file*/


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();

                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Gelvis You need to kill the system service that accepts connection primarily.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Bluetooth socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html) connection to set a client server TCP like connection.

Answer (score 0):

**ON ROOTED DEVICES**, You can just install only two apps on your phone to achieve your goal.

1. XPosed Installer
2. Auto-Accept

This way you hook System service.

```
import android.util.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.*;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod;

public class Tutorial implements IXposedHookLoadPackage
{

    private String TAG="TUTORIAL";
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth"))
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"Not: "+lpparam.packageName);
            return;
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"Yes "+lpparam.packageName);  

        findAndHookMethod("com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppManager", lpparam.classLoader, "isWhitelisted", String.class,new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    Log.v(TAG,"HOOK DONE");
                    param.setResult(true); /* you can compare the sender address(String) with your computer and determine if you return true or just allow the original method to be called after this returns.*/

                }
            });

    }
}
```

For more information, please visit [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379762/8614565) in SO.

I'll post some direct links here.

**Links**

[Dropbox link of the auto accepting app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fuviv2seahf8jf/app.apk?dl=0)

[Dropbox link of the project files (zip)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttl2uqcnoysdwge/auto-accept.zip?dl=0)

[Xposed apk site](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

[Towelroot site to root your phone](https://towelroot.com)

[Auto-Accept github repository](https://github.com/KYHSGeekCode/Auto-Accept)