# Auto accept Bluetooth file transfers

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to programmatically, in Android, auto accept Bluetooth file transfers if the devices are paired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own application which listens to incoming files transfers and accepts them. The connection has to be created as an insecure connection to make the pairing/transfer process automated, without the need for user interaction.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103472/how-to-accept-bluetooth-received-file-in-android-application).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new application that runs as a server is not easy.

So I managed to create an application that makes the work easier.

If you have **ROOTED DEVICE,**
Please visit this [Github repository](https://github.com/KYHSGeekCode/Auto-Accept) and install the app with XPosed Framework.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379762/8614565).

**Edit**

Added cores from the link.

Try this code.

```
import android.util.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.*;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod;

public class Tutorial implements IXposedHookLoadPackage
{

    private String TAG="TUTORIAL";
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth"))
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"Not: "+lpparam.packageName);
            return;
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"Yes "+lpparam.packageName);  

        findAndHookMethod("com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppManager", lpparam.classLoader, "isWhitelisted", String.class,new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    Log.v(TAG,"HOOK DONE");
                    param.setResult(true); /* you can compare the sender address(String) with your computer and determine if you return true or just allow the original method to be called after this returns.*/

                }
            });

    }
}
```

I tested and it **works fine:)**

**Links**

[Dropbox link of the auto accepting app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fuviv2seahf8jf/app.apk?dl=0)

[Dropbox link of the project files (zip)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttl2uqcnoysdwge/auto-accept.zip?dl=0)

[Xposed apk site](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

[Towelroot site to root your phone](https://towelroot.com)