# NFC Pair Bluetooth Connection Android Bidirectional Socket issue

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, bidirectional

Hi I want to connect two android phones application using Bluetooth and NFC.

I am currently sending the UUID and the MAC over NFC from one device to another; 
The issue is that when it comes to opening the sockets I get the following error:
java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed

On the client side of the application:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bluerec);



    JSONObject oneObject = null;

    //NFC
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Parcelable[] messages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

    NdefMessage message = (NdefMessage)messages[0];
    NdefRecord record = message.getRecords()[0];

    payload = new String(record.getPayload());
    String add = null;    
    String uuid = null;

    try {
           oneObject = new JSONObject(payload);
           add = oneObject.getString("MAC");
           uuid = oneObject.getString("UUID");   
    } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(payload);

    UUID uuid2 = UUID.fromString(uuid);

    BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();   
    this.bluetooth = bluetooth;

    BluetoothDevice device = bluetooth.getRemoteDevice(add);
    connectToServerSocket(device, uuid2 );  
}

 private void connectToServerSocket(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
      try{
        BluetoothSocket clientSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

        // Block until server connection accepted.
        clientSocket.connect();

        // Start listening for messages.
        StringBuilder incoming = new StringBuilder();
        listenForMessages(clientSocket, incoming);

        // Add a reference to the socket used to send messages.
        transferSocket = clientSocket;

      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("BLUETOOTH", "Blueooth client I/O Exception", e);
      }
    }
```

And on the Server side:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Bluetooth


    //NFC
    jsonObj = getMacAddress();
    payload = jsonObj.toString();

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    String mimeType = "application/com.example.cpayvendingcomm";
    byte[] mimeBytes = mimeType.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    NdefMessage nfcMessage = new NdefMessage(
        new NdefRecord[] 
        {
            // Create the NFC payload.
            new NdefRecord(
            NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA,
            mimeBytes,
            new byte[0],
            payload.getBytes()),
            // Add the AAR (Android Application Record)
            //NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.paad.nfcbeam")
        });

    nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(nfcMessage, this);

    initBluetooth();

}

 private static final int ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;

 private void initBluetooth() {
      if (!bluetooth.isEnabled()) { 
        // Bluetooth isn't enabled, prompt the user to turn it on.
        Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
      } else {
        // Bluetooth is enabled, initialize the UI.
        initBluetoothUI();
        BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();   
        this.bluetooth = bluetooth;
        startServerSocket(bluetooth);
      }

 }

 private void initBluetoothUI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> deviceList = 
          new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

 BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String remoteDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);

        BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        deviceList.add(remoteDevice);

        Log.d(TAG, "Discovered " + remoteDeviceName);
      }
    };

    private BluetoothSocket transferSocket;

    private UUID startServerSocket(BluetoothAdapter bluetooth) {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c545");
        String name = "bluetoothserver";

        try {
          final BluetoothServerSocket btserver = 
            bluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, uuid);

          Thread acceptThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              try {
                // Block until client connection established.
                BluetoothSocket serverSocket = btserver.accept();
                // Start listening for messages.
                StringBuilder incoming = new StringBuilder();
                listenForMessages(serverSocket, incoming);
                // Add a reference to the socket used to send messages.
                transferSocket = serverSocket;
              } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("BLUETOOTH", "Server connection IO Exception", e);
              }
            }
          });
          acceptThread.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("BLUETOOTH", "Socket listener IO Exception", e);
        }
        return uuid;
      }





    // Listener for messages
    private boolean listening = false;

    private void listenForMessages(BluetoothSocket socket, StringBuilder incoming) {
      listening = true;

      int bufferSize = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      try {
        InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while (listening) {
          bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
          if (bytesRead != -1) {
            String result = "";
            while ((bytesRead == bufferSize) &&
                   (buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)){
              result = result + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
              bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
            }
            result = result + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
            incoming.append(result);
          }
          socket.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message received failed.", e);
      }
      finally {
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing the Bluetooth address assumes you are connecting without prior pairing of the Bluetooth devices. Depending on whether you want to pair the two devices or not you can implement it two ways:

1. No Pairing. Use `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()` instead of `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()` on the client as described in [how to create insecure server connection in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308373/how-to-create-insecure-rfcomm-socket-in-android/5319114#5319114). Use  `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord()` on the server.
2. Pairing with Secure Simple Pairing with passing OOB via NFC. It's a more involved process, beyond what you are asking.