# File transfer without asking permission everytime

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am developing an android app in which I want to send an image file between two devices very quickly. It's like the image will run from first to second, second to first and so on.
The app will ask ONCE for the permission to use your Bluetooth (or if there is any other service to use) at the time app is started, but not at the times when the file is transferred.
I searched for it and got to know that file transfer without permission, is not permitted in Android4+. so Is there any way i can achieve it?

If it can be achieved with any other service than Bluetooth, I would like to know. Any suggestions will help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do it. One is Bluetooth for sure.. Use InsecureRFcomm connection for creating bluetooth socket look at the answer of this question  [How to create Insecure RFCOMM Socket in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308373/how-to-create-insecure-rfcomm-socket-in-android) .. Also I would like to tell you.. if both the android devices have your app then you need not ask permission everytime... and. in my case. I even did not aske permission to switch on the bluetooth... I used bluetoothAdapter.enable(). .. (It is not advised though)

the other way is Wifi p2p or wifi-Direct ..You can find it on the developer's guide..http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html I haven't used it. Please let me know if you do.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I'll tell you after implementation if it works or not.

Comment: You can enable without asking the user but to make the device discoverable you need to ask the user unless there is another way